# Scroll to particular view

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I have home activity on which I have 3 buttons : `Move To A` , `Move To B` and `Move To C`.

On click of these buttons, I navigate to inner activity where I have 3 layouts within a `HorizontalScrollView`, say `A`, `B` and `C` which in turn consists of several views.

Now what I want is , inner activity should navigate to one of the 3 layouts based on clicked button from Home activity i.e.

If `Move To A` on home activity is pressed, inner activity should navigate to Layout `A` and so on...

Possible solution might be to use `ScrollTo()` but it isn't efficient with variable screen sizes.

Any help appreciated.

### Edit

This doesn't work:

```
RelativeLayout LayoutA = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutA);
HorizontalScrollView main = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
main.scrollTo(PoCLayout.getLeft(), 0);
```

Even this doesn't work:

```
main.scrollTo(500, 0);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `main.scrollTo(500,0)` does not work, try :

```
main.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        main.scrollTo(500, 0);
    }
}
```

**Edit : the working solution** in the listener of the button :

```
main.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        main.scrollTo(layoutX.getLeft(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm.. I've done `main.scrollTo(PoCLayout.getLeft(), 0);` inside `run()` and it worked. May I know the reason?

Comment: I don't know the reason. I just remember that I had this problem before and that stackoverflow gave me this solution.

Comment: @yDelouis 
I have an additional question regarding this. Can you help me in solving this problem. Its similar to this problem only
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392655/automatic-scrolling-when-pinch-zoom-event-is-called-in-android

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it will work, but you can try to get the position of your layout A, B or C calling the method `getLeft()` and then use `scrollTo()`.
Example to scroll to layout A : `scrollTo(a.getLeft(), 0);`

Comment: `LayoutA.getLeft()` but it returns me **0** :(

Comment: If it's the first layout it seems normal. Does layoutB.getLeft() return 0 too ?

Comment: Where are you calling `getLeft()` ? You have to wait the content view is build so don't call `getLeft()` in `onCreate()` but call it in the listener of the button, just before `scrollTo()`.

Comment: I called `getLeft()` inside `scrollTo()` only. But doind this within `run()` worked. Any specific reason?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a little Math here

Use `View.getLeft()` and `View.getRight()` then divide calculated width per 2 to scroll to the View center

Comment: `LayoutA.getLeft()` but it returns me **0** :(

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
final  HorizontalScrollView scrollView= (HorizontalScrollView) 
int speed=1000;
findViewById(R.id.main_scrollView);
final View view = findViewById(R.id.your_view); 
ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() { view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);   
                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollView, "scrollY",  (int) view.getX()).setDuration(speed).start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        main.scrollTo(500,500);
    }
}
```

Comment: add now main.scrollTo(500,500);